# Portrait and Landscape mode compatibility in Jquery & HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make my html page tablet compatible, by trying to hide the menu if width is less than height, it works when page loads but when i change the orientation of tablet the menu div remains at its place. Here what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //retrieve current window height
    if (windowWidth < windowHeight) {
        $(".menuArea").hide();
    }
    else {

        $(".menuArea").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for this? You can achieve it with plain media queries. (and of course changing the orientation doesn't change what is displayed - you are doing your test when the DOM is ready, not when the orientation changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **orientationchange** event.

```
function oChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', oChange);
```

Or via jquery

```
 $(window).on('orientationchange', oChange);
```